# Mysql trigger constraint check

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, phpmyadmin

I am not an expert with databases and I need help while I am doing my database project. I am using phpmyadmin version  4.1.14 as my database server. I am required to have a constraint which will make sure that a reader cannot borrow more than 10 books from the library. I am trying to set up a trigger that will run before the BORROWED table is updated to make sure the reader did not borrowed more than 10 books. If the reader has borrowed 10 books already I want to display a message.

I can't get this to work as I keep getting error. Here is my SQL for trigger

```
BEGIN
DECLARE msg varchar(255);
SELECT Count(ReaderID) as Counted from BORROWED 
WHERE RDateTime=null
IF Counted=10 THEN
SET msg='Reader cannot borrow more than 10 books';
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT=msg;
END IF;
END
```

This is the error message I get.
MySQL said: #1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to you MySQL server version for the right syntax yo use near 'IF Counted=10 THEN SET msq='REader cannot borrow more than 10 books'; SIGNAL S' at line 5

Thank you for help !

Comment: Nothing in your sample query matches "ID Counted . . .".  Please post the actual trigger that generates the message.  As a hint, though, saying `as Counted` doesn't set any variable anywhere.

Comment: I am sorry, I have made a typo when typing the question. it is not "ID Counted", it should be "IF Counted". My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining `Counted` as a variable:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE msg varchar(255);
    IF 10 <= (select count(*) from borrowed where rDateTime is NULL) THEN
        SET msg = 'Reader cannot borrow more than 10 books';
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT=msg;
    END IF;
END;
```

Note that I also changed the `= NULL` to `is NULL`, the correct way to do a `NULL` comparison.

Comment: It helped! the only thing is ">=" sign should be "<=". thank you!

Comment: "Try defining `Counted` as a variable" ?